# How can i send 2 seperate embeds into the logs channel one displaying the deleted message and another displaying the deleted image?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

So im making a bot for a friend and I want to log deleted messages, however my code only shows deleted messages and deleted images separately, not sending both embeds like how Dyno does it[image]

Heres the delete log code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message: discord.Message):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(logs_channel_id)
        if not message.attachments:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
            embed.set_author(
                name=message.author.name,
                icon_url=message.author.avatar
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="",
                value=f"{message.author.mention} Deleted a message in {message.channel.mention}",
                inline=False
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="",
                value=message.content,
                inline=False
            )
            
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Message Author: {message.author.id} | Channel ID: {message.channel.id}")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.user.avatar)
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            
        if message.attachments:
            if len(message.attachments) == 1:
                file = message.attachments[0].url
                embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
                embed.set_author(
                    name=message.author.name,
                    icon_url=message.author.avatar
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="",
                    value=f"{message.author.mention} Deleted an image in {message.channel.mention}",
                    inline=False
                )
                embed.set_image(
                    url=file
                )
        
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Message Author: {message.author.id} | Channel ID: {message.channel.id}")
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.user.avatar)
                embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            return
```

Comment: "*... however my code only shows deleted messages and deleted images separately, not sending both embeds*" - I don't really understand this one. Are you saying that your code is just sending one embed instead of two?

Comment: @Dominik Looking at their code, it looks like this is the case

Comment: @Dominik Hi sorry for the confusion, yes the bot is only sending one embed. But i wanted it to send two seperate ones like the example image of dyno i gave. Basically when i delete a message that has an attachment and a piece of text, it only sends the embed with the attachment and not the embed with the piece of text, like Dyno

Answer (score 0):

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_delete(self, message: discord.Message):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
    embed.set_author(
        name=message.author.name,
        icon_url=message.author.avatar
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="",
        value=f"{message.author.mention} Deleted a message in {message.channel.mention}",
        inline=False
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="",
        value=message.content,
        inline=False
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.user.avatar)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    if message.attachments:
        embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Message Author: {message.author.id} | Channel ID: {message.channel.id}")
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(logs_channel_id)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Posting code without any explanation is not recommended

Comment: although there was no explanation, I understood how this works and it worked! Thank you